# Url redirect not working using ip

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use localhost the navigate url is working but when I am using the ip address of the machine the page not found is showing

The code is following

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="LoginLogout" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>

LoginLogout.NavigateUrl = "login.aspx"
LoginLogout.Text = "Login"
```

Comment: Are you talking about just a link, or an actual redirect?

Comment: when i am using 'http://localhost:2001/login.aspx' it redirects to the login.aspx page but when i am using 'http://192.*.*.*:2001/login.aspx' then it is showing page not found

Comment: But where is the redirect? Your code just shows a link as far as I can see.

Comment: When i use localhost:2001/default.aspx in the url and click on log in link it redirects to the login.aspx but when i am using 192.*.*.*:2001/default.aspx and click on the login link then the page not found is showing.Here the NavigateUrl attribute is working for redirect.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a redirect. That sounds like a plain hyperlink. It you really think you've got a redirect, please show it.

Comment: is it 'page not found' or 'Unautorized Access' ? also for localHost try 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) use this IP address >try with 127.0.0.1

or 2) In IIS (I am using IIS 7) under "IP address and domain Restrictions" Add your IP adress. I hope that will help